# how to put the content of a file into a variable with bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to put the content of a file into a variable, this is my code:

```
var=cut -d@ -f1 tmp2
```

I also tried with piping, let var and etc.
How do I make it work?

Comment: Looks like you are going to finish off your homework early today! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var="$( cut -d@ -f1 tmp2 )"
```

The `$( .. )` is call command substitution. Cmd substitution can also be performed with ` ... ` pairs per @JanVorcak's solution but that syntax is considered deprecated, unless you're expecting to use old vendor Unix like Solaris WITH the bourne shell. Incidentally, you say that var now equals 'cat file.txt'. You must be using the wrong char, most likely the single quote char `'`, instead of the back-quote char "`".

As your title says you're trying to 'put the content of a file into a varible', I'm surrounding the output of cut with " ... ". Now the value of var is the complete output of `cut ...`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about deprecation of `` +1, btw @shellter could you please explain to me why to use `cut -d@ -f1 tmp2` instead of `cat tmp2`? does it have some special purpose? thank you

Comment: try this. `echo 'fld1@fld2\nfld3@fld4\n' | cut -d@ -f1`. you should get fld1 fld3 on separate lines. If tmp2 contained the same text, you would get both lines complete. If that is not  clear, I can edit my answer so it will be easier to understand. Also back-ticks considered deprecated in 1995 per http://www.amazon.com/New-KornShell-Command-Programming-Language/dp/0131827006/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1322430885&sr=1-3  :-) Thanks for your interest and good luck to all!

Comment: one more thing. note that you usually need to refer to $var inside of dbl-quotes going forward,  for example `case "$var" in *pat1* ) xxx ;; *pat2* ) yyy;; esac` OR `echo "$var" > newFile`. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
var=`cut -d@ -f1 tmp2`
```

Or this

```
var=$(cut -d@ -f1 tmp2)
```

Comment: the second is the better way as you can nest them.

Comment: @DanD. and the quoting/expansion behaves like in a regular command line

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you, you want to load a file into variable like this?

```
v=`cat file.txt`
```

Comment: you understood me right, but when I'm doing what you wrote it puts the string cat file.txt into v....

Comment: have you used `` around `cat file.txt`?

Comment: @user1067642 You're probably using the wrong character. It's the one below the tilde (`~`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the file contents, with bash you'd write

```
var=$(< filename)
```

[documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)